# How can I load a component based on the domain in a Nuxt / Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a system that needs to load a different dynamic Vue component depending on the incoming domain name. I can identify the host in a middleware function within the context parameter, but don't know how I can access the incoming domain in a component script. Is there a way to access it directly in a component or a way to pass data from middleware into the component?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have been able to access it with this.$nuxt.$options.context.isServer from a component method. I am not sure if this is the best way, but it seems to work for me thus far.

Comment: Please don't use `context.isServer` as it's deprecated and slated for removal in Nuxt 2.0. Instead, please use `process.server`

Comment: For my situation, passing data from the middleware into the component before rendering seems to be the best idea. If there is information how to accomplish this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> load a different dynamic Vue component depending on the incoming
>   domain name

You could make use of `nuxtServerInit()` method.

- This method will run only on the server side
- You need not use `process.server` to detect whether the control flow is with server or client
- This method has access to `context` object
- You have to use `nuxtServerInit()` along with `Vuex`.
- `Vuex` is enabled by default in Nuxt. So you are free to use Vuex.

Below code will get executed on the server side whenever a new page is requested.

You can write your **"** *redirect to different page based on domain* **"** logic here

```
actions: {
    nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, reqObject) {
      console.log("url ", reqObject.req.url);
      console.log("method ", reqObject.req.method);
      console.log("host ", reqObject.req.headers.host);
      if(reqObject.req.headers.host == "mydomain.com"){
          reqObject.redirect("/anynuxtpage");
      }
      else{
          //do nothing. page corresponding to the current route will be loaded
      }
    }
}
```

if you make use of this approach then you need not think about invoking any middleware

**Reference**

**nuxtserverinit** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action

**vuex-store** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store